# Installing a specific version of a package with yarn doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg, package.json, framer-motion

I use framer-motion in a React App. The latest version - 4.1.13 - breaks my ui. I need to downgrade to the previous version - 4.1.2 - (yes, the versioning seems weird, but 4.1.2 is actually prior to 4.1.13, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/framer-motion).

I run the command `yarn upgrade framer-motion@^4.1.2`. In `package.json`, the package becomes `4.1.2`, but in `yarn.lock`, the package's version is still `4.1.13`:

```js
framer-motion@^4.1.2:
  version "4.1.13"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/framer-motion/-/framer-motion-4.1.13.tgz#0a7f096113a0f80f11116c1a73da9b81523324cd"
  integrity sha512-E72PyzHXsie1IGcEFMGM3OJsVbtmpS8vcnDjh6tdeCaP7stoioZpmKZcx7c87giymAyuSSWvsGGdVnDGRzRX6g==
  dependencies:
    framesync "5.3.0"
    hey-listen "^1.0.8"
    popmotion "9.3.5"
    style-value-types "4.1.4"
    tslib "^2.1.0"
  optionalDependencies:
    "@emotion/is-prop-valid" "^0.8.2"
```

I have of course did a `rm -rf node_modules && yarn`. It doesn't change anything.

Comment: Maybe you should try with `yarn upgrade framer-motion@4.1.2`? adding `^` allow for bug relase upgrade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command you ran: `yarn upgrade framer-motion@^4.1.2` allows any version in the below range:

```
>=4.1.2 <5.0.0
```

`4.1.13` falls in this range so yarn is probably picking up latest. Run `yarn upgrade framer-motion@4.1.2` to install the specific version.

---

If it doesn't work, as a last resort try adding a:

```
"resolutions":
   "framer-motion": "4.1.2"
}
```